# accessing webserver on desktop PC through wifi dongle from a tablet

Tags: usb, webserver, wireless-networking, localhost, dongle

I am running windows 7 on my desktop PC and have installed tomcat webserver.  I'm able to bring up the default homepage using http://:8080 (or, http://:8080) on the desktop browser.

I have a D-Link USB wifi dongle and the drivers are installed successfully.  I'd want to access the default homepage on my tablet's browser (through wifi) by accessing http://:8080).  Is this possible?  If yes, i'd need pointers on this front.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to setup a new ad-hoc connection unless you're connecting both the pc and the tablet to the same access point.

If your are doing so, you just need to find out the PC's ip address on the wifi adapter's properties and enter your PC's ip address :8080 on the tablet's browser